# Need to Connect Other Remote Server Using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, ssh, remote-access

I need to connect my another server **like DigitalOcean, Vultr or Any Other** Third Party Server using SSH or Any Other Method with **Operating System Ubuntu 16.X or 14.X.** and framework is Laravel.

I am still finding something to connect using Laravel because after Successfully connecting that server in laravel Framework I need to put logic to install some software on Linux which is based as my Education and I need to put that logic where I click reboot from the web app and server will reboot.

**Note:**
the server is from the third party. I take username and password to connect server. I need remote access to connect that server using laravel ramework.

Please Help Me Guys, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: So, you need to run command on your server via laravel? 
Maybe you need this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/envoy)

Comment: Like Example server IP X.X.X.X and User Root and Password XXX so, I need to connect that server in laravel framework and I manage that server using laravel Like I restart, shutdown, install LAMP Understand? build something like [this](https://serverpilot.io/)

Comment: I think this is a very very bad idea... You must use some ssh client, like putty